# socketio.emit doesn't work netty socketio

Tags: java, spring-boot, socket.io, netty-socketio

I'm working with socketio and netty with java and I'm new to both of them.

my client side code looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title >webSocket test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-cPwlPLvBTa3sKAgddT6krw0cJat7egBga3DJepJyrLl4Q9/5WLra3rrnMcyTyOnh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    < !-- New Bootstrap core CSS file-->
    <!-- Optional Bootstrap theme file (generally not necessary to import) -->
    <!- -jQuery file. Be sure to introduce before bootstrap.min.js -->

    <!-- The latest Bootstrap core JavaScript file-->
    <script type=" text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            /**
             * The socket.emit("event name", "parameter data") method of the
             front-end js is used when triggering the back-end custom message event, * front-end js The socket.on("event name", anonymous function (data sent by the server to the client)) for monitoring server-side events
             **/

            //io({path: 'ws://localhost:9099/', transports: ['websocket'] ,upgrade: false});

            var socket = io.connect("ws://localhost:9099",{transports: ['websocket'] ,upgrade: false});
            var firstconnect = true;
            if(firstconnect) {
                console.log("First connection initialization");
                //Monitor server connection event
                socket.on('connect',function(){
                    socket.emit('messageEvent', 'Hello server');
                    console.log("First connection success");
                    $("#tou").html("Connect to the server successfully!");
                     });

                //Monitor server shutdown service event

                socket.on('disconnect', function(){
                    $("#tou").html("Disconnected from the server!");
                    });
                //Monitor server Send message event
                socket.on('responseEvent', function(data) {
                    console.log('data');
                    $("#msg").html($("#msg").html() + "<br/>" + data);
                } );
                firstconnect = false;
            } else {
                console.log("why?");
                socket.socket.reconnect();
            }

            $('#send').bind('click', function() {
                send();
            });

            function send(){
                if (socket != null) {
                    var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
                    var title = "message";
                    var obj = {message:message,title:title};
                    var str = JSON.stringify(obj);
                    socket.emit("messageEvent",str);
                    console.log("message event" , str);

                } else {
                    alert('Send');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="page-header" id="tou">
    webSocket Demo
</div>
<div class="well" id="msg">
</div>
<div class="col-lg">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="send Message..." id="message">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="send" >send</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
</div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row --><br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

The event handler is as shown below.

```
@Component
public class MessageEventHandler {

    private static final Logger logger  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageEventHandler.class);

    public static ConcurrentMap<String, SocketIOClient> socketIOClientMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


    @Autowired
    private RedissonClient redisson;

    @Resource
    private SocketIOServer socketIOServer;

    @OnConnect
    public void  onConnect(SocketIOClient client){
        Map<String,Object> clientMap = new HashMap<>(16);

        client.sendEvent("responseEvent", client.getSessionId().toString()+": "+ "hello");

        if(client!=null){
            String room = client.getHandshakeData().getSingleUrlParam("room");
            String nameSpace = client.getNamespace().getName();
            logger.info("namespace {} ",nameSpace);

            String sessionId = client.getSessionId().toString();
            logger.info("namespace, room={}, sessionId={},namespace={}",room,sessionId,nameSpace);
            if(StringUtils.isEmpty(room)){
                //client.joinRoom(room);
                clientMap.put("rooms",room);
            }
            clientMap.put("createTime", LocalDateTime.now().toString());
            redisson.getBucket("room"+sessionId).trySet(clientMap);

        }

        return;
    }

    /**
     * Triggered when the client closes the connection
     *
     * @param client
     */
    @OnDisconnect
    public void onDisconnect(SocketIOClient client) {
        logger.info("client:" + client.getSessionId() + "disconnected");
    }

    /**
     * Client events
     *
     * @param client  　
     * @param request
     * @param msg    　
     */
    @OnEvent(value = "messageEvent")
    public void onMessageEvent(SocketIOClient client, AckRequest request, String msg) {

        System.out.println("haha");
        logger.info("message ：" + msg);

        //Post the message back
        JSONObject jsonObject = JSON.parseObject(msg);
        String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
        Collection<SocketIOClient> clients = socketIOServer.getBroadcastOperations().getClients();
        for (SocketIOClient clientByRoom : clients) {
            clientByRoom.sendEvent("responseEvent", client.getSessionId().toString()+":   "+message);
        }
    }

}
```

The server starter code is shown below.

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class SocketServerRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocketServerRunner.class);

    @Resource
    private SocketIOServer socketIOServer;

    @Resource
    private PubSubStore pubSubStore;

    @Autowired
    private RedissonClient redisson;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("socketIOServer ");
        socketIOServer.start();

        pubSubStore.subscribe(PubSubType.DISPATCH, data -> {
            Collection<SocketIOClient> clients = null;
            String room = data.getRoom();
            String namespace = data.getNamespace();
            Packet packet = data.getPacket();
            String jsonData = packet.getData();
            if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(namespace)){
                SocketIONamespace socketIONamespace = socketIOServer.getNamespace(namespace);
                if(StringUtils.isEmpty(room)){
                    clients = socketIONamespace.getRoomOperations(room).getClients();
                }
            }else{
                clients = socketIOServer.getBroadcastOperations().getClients();
            }

            if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(clients)){
                for (SocketIOClient client : clients) {
                    client.sendEvent("messageEvent",jsonData);
                }
            }
        }, DispatchMessage.class);
       // addNameSpace(socketIOServer);
    }
```

I'm getting a connection registration on the `OnConnect` annoted method, but the method seems to run two times cause I get the log twice while the socket connects. I don't know why it happens.

But even worse is the emit method doesn't work that is written in client side javascript. There is no error. The log below the emit is executed. But the `OnEvent` annoted method in the java EventHandler doesn't seem to detect it.

Can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently it seems the problem is with the libraries. There is some compatibility issue with newer versions of socketio client library with netty dependencies for java and it is causing the weird problems.

My dependency for netty socketio is shown below which obviously is the latest as of answering this question.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.corundumstudio.socketio</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-socketio</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.19</version>
        </dependency>
```

And for the client library to work smoothly I had to downgrade the library from 3.X.X to 2.X.X .

In my case from

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-cPwlPLvBTa3sKAgddT6krw0cJat7egBga3DJepJyrLl4Q9/5WLra3rrnMcyTyOnh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: works like a charm on spring boot + react js -> version must be same

Comment: i was working on it about 1 week. Thanks a lot! it works!